# Tableau CustomSQL Cast NUMERIC to FLOAT

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I am writing a customSQL in Tableau to import data from BigQuery.

Columns in BigQuery View
Column1 | VALUE(Type = Numeric)

I want to CAST the "VALUE" column to Float, so that the column appears in Tableau

My current SQL query:
SELECT Column1, CAST(VALUE as Float) from Table 1

The above statement is giving me an error. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work using the below SQL

SELECT Column1, CAST(VALUE as Float64) AS VALUE from Table 1.

I was missing "AS VALUE" in my previous SQLstatement.

Note: Tableau v2020.3 will support Numeric data type

Answer (score 0):

According to this [information on the BigQuery site](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#casting) the data type should be FLOAT64.

CAST(values AS FLOAT64)

(Original Answer pre-comment)
You are able to convert it to a float in Tableau. FLOAT([YourField])

Comment: Tableau doesn't recognise NUMERIC values from BigQuery so it doesn't even bring the field in if i query it without casting/changing the type. Hence I am writing customSQL in Tableau with CAST to bring the VALUE field in. Assuming my statement has an error.     SELECT Column1, CAST(VALUE as Float) from Table 1

Comment: I've edited the answer, looks like the data type FLOAT may not exist in bigquery and it should be FLOAT64

Comment: Tried this but no luck :                                                                                         SELECT Projectex,CAST(VALUE as FLOAT64) FROM `im-test-209122.PPM_UAT.SAP_PS_CONSOLIDATED`

Comment: I don't know then. You could try INT64 instead, see if it makes any difference. I'm assuming you have tested your SELECT statement in bigquery as well. This is all I find online https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/numeric-type-bigquery-fields-missing-in-tableau-desktop, where it suggests casting, as you're doing.